# SQL Plus formatting a nested table column

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm having issues displaying the nested table column data as some of the records are trailing off, is there a way to sort out the format where the `order_items` are below one another?

```
SQL> SELECT order_id, billing_name, items FROM orders;

  ORDER_ID BILLING_NAME    ITEMS(ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, SELLER_ID, SUB_ORDER_NUMBER, QUANTITY, CONDITION, UNIT_PRICE, COST_CHARGE, TOTAL)                                                                
---------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                      
         1 John Smith      ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(1, 1, 1, '3026143053', 1, 'Brand new ', 53.49, 0, 53.49), ORDER_ITEM(1, 2, 2, '3029608429', 1, 'Brand new ', 1.9                                      
         2 Sarah Jones     ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(2, 3, 3, '3054134547', 2, 'Brand New ', 53.49, 0, 106.98), ORDER_ITEM(2, 4, 4, '3053273551', 1, 'Brand New ', 29                                      
         3 Tom Sharpe      ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(3, 2, 2, '3073748221', 1, 'Brand New ', 7.97, 2, 9.97), ORDER_ITEM(3, 6, 5, '3146744589', 1, 'Brand New ', 779.9                                      
         4 Derek Miller    ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(4, 4, 4, '3124685316', 1, 'Brand New ', 299, 0, 299), ORDER_ITEM(4, 5, 5, '3157302741', 1, 'Brand New ', 639.95,                                      
         5 Mark Dwight     ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(5, 1, 1, '3246315960', 1, 'Brand New ', 53.49, 0, 53.49), ORDER_ITEM(5, 2, 2, '3354174322', 1, 'Brand New ', 1.9                                      
         6 Lucy Nolan      ORDER_ITEMS(ORDER_ITEM(6, 4, 4, '3821362630', 1, 'Brand New ', 299, 0, 299), ORDER_ITEM(6, 3, 3, '3902471881', 1, 'Brand New ', 53.49,                                                                            

6 rows selected.

SQL> SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a result like this?

```
ORDER_ID BILLING_NAME    PRODUCT_ID SELLER_ID SUB_ORDER_ QUANTITY CONDITION UNIT_PRICE COST_CHARGE    TOTAL
-------- --------------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- --------- ---------- ----------- --------
       1 John Smith               1         1 3026143053        1 Brand new      53.49           0    53.49
                                  2         2 3029608429        1 Brand new       1.90           1     2.90
       2 Sarah Jones              3         3 3054134547        2 Brand New      53.49           0   106.98
                                  4         4 3053273551        1 Brand New      29.22           0    29.22
       3 Tom Sharpe               2         2 3073748221        1 Brand New       7.97           2     9.97
                                  6         5 3146744589        1 Brand New     779.95           0   779.95
       4 Derek Miller             4         4 3124685316        1 Brand New     299.00           0   299.00
                                  5         5 3157302741        1 Brand New     639.95           0   639.95
       5 Mark Dwight              1         1 3246315960        1 Brand New      53.49           0    53.49
                                  2         2 3354174322        1 Brand New       1.90           1     1.90
       6 Lucy Nolan               4         4 3821362630        1 Brand New     299.00           0   299.00
                                  3         3 3902471881        1 Brand New      53.49           1    54.49
```

You can do this with a combination of two things: A query that flattens the data (unnesting the nested table column - generating multiple rows per `order_id`) and SQL*Plus formatting commands - in this case the `break` command to show each `(order_id, billing_name)` just once for each group. You may also need/want to format the individual columns, so that a unit price of 1.9, for example, is shown as 1.90, but that is an unrelated (and much easier) problem; I don't show how to do that.

So, here is the SQL*Plus command first, and then the query. Note that your records in the nested table have an `order_id` attribute; that is supposed to be the `order_id` you have in the table already, so I left it out from the query (and its output). Indeed, it is not clear why it's part of the record, if the "tables" are nested within a parent table that has the `order_id` already; I will let you philosophise about that.

```
SQL> break on order_id on billing_name

SQL> select o.order_id, o.billing_name, product_id, seller_id, sub_order_number,
  2         quantity, condition, unit_price, cost_charge, total
  3  from   orders o left outer join lateral (select * from table(o.items))
  4                  on null is null
  5  /
```

The ***outer*** (lateral) join is necessary for the case when `items` is atomically `null`, and also for the case when `items` is an empty nested table. Both situations are possible; I assume you are aware that the two are not the same.

Comment: Thanks that worked well but for some reason it added one row into a new table which I'm unsure about.

`ORDER_ID BILLING_NAME    PRODUCT_ID  SELLER_ID SUB_ORDER_   QUANTITY CONDITION  UNIT_PRICE COST_CHARGE      TOTAL
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
         6 Lucy Nolan               4          4 3821362630          1 Brand New         299           0        299
                                    3          3 3902471881          1 Brand New       53.49           0      53.49`

Comment: Found a solution by setting the pagesize `SET PAGESIZE 999` thank you for your help